# How to use fully functioning JsonPath in angular 2+?

Tags: jsonpath, angular10

I followed https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath. Tried a way to include external js file, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

import jsonPath worked after -

```
import * as jsonPath from 'jsonpath/jsonpath';
```

JsonPath plush also worked [JSONPath-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus) which is same as of Jsonpath. I have following coding snippet which is working for me-

install JSONPath-plus

```
npm install jsonpath-plus
```

angular.json file

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jsonpath-plus/dist/index-umd.js",
    "src/assets/js/jsonpath.js"
]
```

jsonpath.js have following code -

```
function jsonPath() {
  return JSONPath;
}
```

Now use this function in ts file with declaring it like below -

```
declare const jsonPath: any;
// use it like
 jsonPath().JSONPath(path, json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Install JSONPath-plus:

```
npm install jsonpath-plus
```

In your component file .ts put this:

```
declare var require: any;
const jsonpath = require('jsonpath-plus');
```

somewhere in your component:

```
jsonpath.JSONPath('$.bar', {bar: 777});
```